# Why is iwloc=near hiding entire google map instead of juts the address bubble?

Tags: google-maps, hide, embed

When I change the "iwloc=A" property to "iwloc=near" in my Google map embed code (to remove the address bubble), the entire map disappears!   Anyone else experience this or might know why??

Answer (score 0):

Recently also faced this problem. Try `iwloc=addr`.